# Dollar sign before a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq, dollar-sign

I have this sample code to create a new data frame 'new_data' from the existing data frame 'my_data'.

```
new_data = NULL
n = 10 #this number correspond to the number of rows in my_data
conditions = c("Bas_A", "Bas_T", "Oper_A", "Oper_T") # the vector characters correspond to the target column names in my_data
for (cond in conditions){
    for (i in 1:n){
        new_data <- rbind(new_data, c(cond, my_data$cond[i]))
    }
}
```

The problem is that `my_data$cond` (where cond is a variable, and not the column name) is not accepted.

**How can I call a column of a data frame by using, after the dollar sign, a variable value?**

Comment: `$` is not really meant to be used programatically. It is meant to be a convenience for interactive use. Try using `mydata[i,cond]` instead. However, looking at your code I think you might benefit from looking at the `reshape` function, or indeed the `reshape2` package...

Comment: Note that `my_data` is a `data.frame` and `new_data` is a `matrix`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To access a column, use:

```
my_data[ , cond]
```

or

```
my_data[[cond]]
```

The `i`th row can be accessed with:

```
my_data[i, ]
```

Combine both to obtain the desired value:

```
my_data[i, cond]
```

or

```
my_data[[cond]][i]
```

Comment: cant we use `c$column`, where `c` is a matrix? I was getting `Error in c$col1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`...

Comment: @Mahesha999 You can't use `$` with matrices.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if for example we wanted to leverage the partial matching supported by `$` offers, couldn't we use something like `'$'(data,something(cond))` with something being one or a mix of functions that I don't fully understand such `as.symbol`, `as.expression`, `quote` `enquote` `substitute`etc ?

Comment: I want to ADD 106 columns to a dataframe that are the length of the dataframe but are filled with 0's. How do I loop over this?
for (i in vector) { df$i <- vector(,lengthdf) }   ???

Answer (score 5):

I guess you need `get()`.

For example,
`get(x,list)`, where `list` is the list and `x` is the variable(can be a string), which equals `list$x`.

But in `get(x,list)`, `x` can be a variable while using `$`, `x` cannot be a variable.

Answer (score 1):

`$` works on columns, not individual column objects. It's a form of vectorization. The code

```
corrections$BookDate = as.Date(corrections$BookDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

converts the contents of the `BookDate` column of the `corrections` table from strings to `Date` objects. It performs it in one operation, assignment.

Do the following and it will fix your problem:

```
new_data <- rbind(new_data, c(cond, my_data$cond))
```