# Dollar sign and for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse

Suppose I have a dataframe with 16 variables named : Amount_day_1, Amount_day_2 ..
I would like to take the mean of each

What I thought of doing is :

```
for (i in 1:16){
  !!as.name(paste0("Mean_Amount_Day_", i) <- 
         mean(df$!!as.name(paste0("Amount_Day_", i)))
}
```

But it really does not work. In fact I really don't know how to select a variable with the dollar sign if it is within a `for` loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389318/dollar-sign-before-a-variable seem relevant

Answer (score 3):

We could do this with `colMeans` to create a single `named` `vector` of means

```
colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

NOTE: It is not recommended to create multiple objects in the global env

---

In a `for` loop, if we are creating objects use `assign`

```
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
     assign(paste0("Mean_Amount_Day_", i), mean(df[[i]], na.rm = TRUE))
 }
```

columns can be subset by either column name or by index.  As the OP mentioned that they need the `mean` of all the columns and is looping by index, use the index to extract the column.  Also, there is no need to convert to symbol with `as.name` nor use any `!!`.  Instead, use `[[` for subsetting